# BigQuery Partitioned Table (on DAY) it does not partition - python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a problem with creating and inserting data into a partitioned table on BigQuery.

My script downloads some data about the last 7 days daily. I save them in a dataframe and then load them on a Big Query partitioned table.

Yesterday the script saved the data of the previous 7 days to the BigQuery table (between 2022-02-14 and 2022-02-20).
Today it saved the data from 7 days ago (between 2022-02-15 and 2022-02-21), but there are no longer those of the previous 7 days that it had saved yesterday (for example, there are no more data for the day 2022-02-14).

This is my code:

```
 schema = [
            bigquery.SchemaField("Date", "DATE", "REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("Advertiser", "STRING", "REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("AdvertiserId", "INTEGER", "REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("Campaign", "STRING", "REQUIRED"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("CampaignId", "INTEGER", "REQUIRED")
    ]

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=schema,
        write_disposition="WRITE_TRUNCATE",
        time_partitioning=bigquery.TimePartitioning(
            type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
            field="Date",  # Name of the column to use for partitioning.
        ),
    )

    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, MY_PROJECT_ID.MY_DATASET.MY_TABLE_NAME), job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.
    job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.
```

Why is the partition not working?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, it is less that the table isn't partitioning but rather the data from previous executions are not there as you would expect.

Your write_disposition is currently set to `WRITE_TRUNCATE` meaning the table gets emptied each time the load job runs.  So the only data you will ever have is from the latest run.

You have a couple options:

1. Change this to a DML statement and merge based on the date and possibly other criteria.
2. Add an additional column like LoadDateTime that is a current timestamp and change your write_disposition to `WRITE_APPEND`.  This way you can distinct out the latest load for each date in a view later.